# How to close browser with ending browser session in webdriverio?

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

I have following test cases - in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
afterTest: async function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {

await browser.end(); // Error thrown browser.end is not a function
// await browser.closewindows(); // No session found after test 1 execute
// await browser.close(); // Error thrown browser.end is not a function
},
beforeTest: async function (test, context) {
    await browser.url("/");
    await browser.maximizeWindow();
}
```

In Test File:

```
Describe("Suite 1", async () => {
it("test 1", async () => {
 - perform different task on browser
 - logout()
});
it("test 2", async () => {
 - perform different task on browser
 - logout()
});
it("test 3", async () => {
 - perform different task on browser
 - logout()
});
});
```

I want to open browser on EACH TEST (it block) under describe block and once EACH TEST is completed I want to close browser. and so on for each it block.

I have used close(), closewindow() and end() methods but no use. Error commented near each method.